# What is space? How to understand it intuitively?

Tags: functions, soft-question

This is a subjective question. I am starting to study machine learning. I only can come with a vague understanding of mathematical spaces. Spaces play important role in my understanding of the subject. I'd like to understand how someone would can imagine a more objective idea of space.

I understand functions or mappings as a way to bind spaces together. Am I in the right path?

Comment: "Space" is not a term that has a specific definition. I think given the machine learning context you probably mean "vector space", which is a set in which you are allowed to do addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Well, let's say you have something thought that is defined by a set of numbers. Very loosely, the range in which those numbers are defined is a space.

Comment: I think what would be useful in your case is considering space as a "whole" which is consisted by "objects", which are governed by some "rules/relations". These "objects" and "relations" can be totally abstract and serve various intuitional meanings. (Even the whole of cooking recipes could make a space since it contains ingredients/objects and relations/combinations). What you have to do in a mathematical aspect is define the objects and relations in a way that will serve your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spaces are sets of mathematical objects that possess some kind of mathematical structure. Generally, we are interested in functions that link spaces together while (hopefully) preserving or transforming that structure predictably.

If that's sounds abstract or vague, it's because it is (intentionally). We want generic descriptions that will apply to many different kinds of objects of study. You can look at specific examples to get an idea of how this plays out, e.g. vector spaces, metric spaces, inner product spaces, topological spaces, etc.

Comment: I cannot upvote yet. Sorry. "transforming that structure predictably" can you please give little more on this?

Comment: @vanangamudi For example, take the real numbers with addition and the transformation $f(x) = e^{x}$. That transformation takes the additive structure and turns it into a multiplicative structure in the positive reals. So, $f(x + y) = e^{x + y} = e^x \cdot e^y = f(x) \cdot f(y)$.

Comment: thanks @michael. that was intuitive.